# How to make video suggestions flex item same height as the video flex item?

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox

I am working on a personal UI design project, and I wanted to add a video section on the landing page. The video section consists of two flex columns, a video player and in the second column, a vertically scrollable div with suggestions. I am pretty new to CSS flex, and can't understand why the scrollable div is not the same height as the video column.

I need to make the scrollable div a fixed height otherwise it would expand its height until all the elements inside it are visible, and I don't want that, I just want it to be a scrollable div.

Here is how it currently looks like:

[image]

And this is my markup:

```html
<div class="video">
  <video src="videos/main.mp4" />
  <div class="suggestions">
    <div class="suggestion">
      <img src="thumbs/1.jpg" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
        <p>29 june 2019</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suggestion">
      <img src="thumbs/1.jpg" />
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
        <p>29 june 2019</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.video {
  display: flex;
}

.video video {
  flex: 1.5;
}

.video .suggestions {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I would love to know how I can make the scrollable div the same height as the video div while maintaining the responsiveness of the video. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to .video .suggestions {height: xxxx }

```css
.flex-wrap{display:flex;}
.flex-left{flex:1.5;}
.flex-right{flex:1;position:relative;}
.video-wrap{position:relative;padding:56.25% 0 0;} /* 16:9 */
.video-player{display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}
.video-recom{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow-y:scroll;}
.video-recom-item img{max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
 <div class="flex-left">
  <div class="video-wrap">
   <iframe class="video-player" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BzYnNdJhZQw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="flex-right">
  <div class="video-recom">
   <div class="video-recom-item">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bukchon-hanok-village-seoul-south-600w-718460350.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
     <p>29 june 2019</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="video-recom-item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/17/05/16/myeongdong-326136_1280.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
     <p>29 june 2019</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="video-recom-item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/17/05/16/myeongdong-326136_1280.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
     <p>29 june 2019</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="video-recom-item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/17/05/16/myeongdong-326136_1280.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
     <p>29 june 2019</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="video-recom-item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/17/05/16/myeongdong-326136_1280.jpg" />
    <div class="caption">
     <h3>lorem ipsum dolor siet amet</h3>
     <p>29 june 2019</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div><!-- //.video-recom-scroll -->

 </div>

</div>
```